# Detect if portion of a div's Background-image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page overlay `div` which is having a `background-image`. the background image is centered on screen and it is having a mock button 'dismiss' (in image itself) on click which removes overlay. I want to detect if user clicks only that mock button area in that image. For better understanding, Lets say the button area is at 45% from top and 45% from left of the image edge.

currently I do remove overlay on click anywhere on image. I just want to confine the click to the button area alone. Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your sample code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Make a div and align it where you want to click and make the function on that div instead of the image

Answer (score 1):

With html 5 you can create maps on the image where the user can click and take an action on that, have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use image mapping like

```
<img src="myImg.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="MyImageWithBtn" usemap="#imgmapExample">

<map name="imgmapExample">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,80" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
</map>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

PS: Give `coords` value based on button's location

[**Image-Maps.com**](http://www.image-maps.com/) Helps you to find the coordinates of your image